# How does the copper loss vary with frequency?

Tags: transformer, electricity

In the context of a transformer, how does the copper loss vary with frequency? Is it greater at higher frequencies?

Comment: -1 lack of research

Comment: The velocity of movement INTO a metal, by electrons, is about 1 million times slower than the speed of light, that is some meters per second. I recall standard PCB copper foil having about 150 nanoseconds risetime, in a dispersive RCRCRCRCR waveform.

Answer (score 3):

It is greater at higher frequencies due to skin effect and proximity effect; both of which are interrelated. Go google these terms and you will see that as frequency increases the current density increases at the surface of a conductor and reduces at the centre. That is skin effect and it increase wire resistance.

Proximity effect is when two wires carrying the same high frequency current interact magnetically and current is further restricted (above that of skin effect) due to the proximity of the wires.

## Skin effect:

[image]

## Proximity effect:

[image]

[Picture source](https://www.electricaleasy.com/2016/08/skin-effect-and-proximity-effect.html).

Comment: Hmm, the largest change will be due to changes in the inductance.  The transformer will become less efficient as frequency rises and copper losses may even fall while the iron losses rise and the power handling vanishes.  High frequency (100kHz) transformers use foil/strip/ribbon windings and this would make skin effects worse, I think it is to improve the inductance characteristics.

Comment: @KalleMP Inductance changes? Do you mean leakage reactance increases?

Comment: A transformer with an iron core will have a lot more hysteresis losses as the frequency climbs.  Copper losses are a result of RMS current in the copper and not related to where in the copper the current occurs, with skin effect the resistance would climb, current would drop more.  I cannot see a good way for the current to generally increase with frequency.  Inductive resistance will climb, reducing current. I tried to find a good link, here is a basic one.  -  https://www.edn.com/design/components-and-packaging/4369085/Using-a-power-transformer-at-a-frequency-it-wasn-t-designed-for

Comment: Why don’t you make an answer of your thoughts.

Comment: Initially because the question was one of those slated for removal and I wanted to just add a heads-up to your answer because it did not seem fully relevant and now because I am not sure of my facts, they are more gut feel than research. I might spend a few more minutes to see if someone has done the research.

Comment: this might just me not being familiar with terminology, but hysteresis loss takes place in the core, not in the copper, so isn't that a core loss instead of a copper loss?

Comment: Hysteresis is a core loss and that loss increases the losses in the wire so indeed bigger hysteresis losses means bigger copper losses but hysteresis losses are not frequency dependant.